# CSS footer background not showing up

Tags: css, background, footer

I have the background image of my main page set in the in the body{} of my css file. Is that my first mistake?

```
body{
    background-image:url('img/bg-white.png');
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I want to create a background image for my footer. So I add this to the bottom of the CSS

```
#footer-background{
    background-image:url('img/footer-background.jpg');
    z-index:1;
}
```

It's not showing up. Is it being overlapped by the original background? Or is there more to it?

Comment: Can you post your html as well? That way we can see what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a shot in the dark, need more info for a conclusive answer, but it may be that you haven't specified a height or width for your footer.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/zmBG7/)**

```
#footer-background{
    background-image:url('img/footer-background.jpg');
    z-index:1;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Works thanks. I didn't know I had to do that. Were you being sarcastic? lmao

Comment: @mike I wasn't sure without seeing the related HTML, but took a shot anyway. If this solved your problem hit the check mark next to the answer to mark it as accepted, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217863 for more info